# Unexpected Token - List

Tags: apex

I have something like the following in an Apex class:

```
public class Picker 
{
    public static List<Type__c> getTypes()
    {
        List<Type__c> list = [select Name from Type__c where Name = 'Person'];
        return list;
    }
}
```

Which gives the following error:

Error: Compile Error: unexpected token: 'List' at line 5 column 8

However, turning into the following is fine:

```
public class Picker
{
    public static List<Type__c> getTypes()
    {
        return [select Name from Type__c where Name = 'Person'];
    }
}
```

Why does the first code segment not work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"List" is a reserved keyword and hence it cant be used as a variable name .You can change the name and should work

```
public class Picker{
   public static List<Type__c> getTypes(){
      List<Type__c> listtype= [select Name from Type__c where Name = 'Person'];
     return listtype;
  }
}
```

Comment: Interesting, it didn't even occur to me that keywords were case insensitive.  Thanks.

Comment: The instructor kind of harped on it and I still made that very same mistake. I guess it's ingrained from Java...

Answer (score 1):

Change your variable name from list to listTypes and that should fix it up.

For reference see this link [here](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_qs_core_concepts.htm):

> **Naming Variables, Methods and Classes**
>
> You cannot use any of the Apex reserved keywords when naming
>   variables, methods or classes. These include words that are part of
>   Apex and the Force.com platform, such as list, test, or account, as
>   well as [reserved keywords](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_reserved_words.htm).